# Trying to Scrape multiple urls, can only scrape 1. (Any way to generate multiple URL list)?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ["https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?product_list_limit=25", "https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?p=2&product_list_limit=25"]
for url in urls:
    html = requests.get(urls).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    products = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "product details product-item-details"})
    all_product = []

for product in products:
    product_details = dict()
    product_details['name'] = product.find('a').text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['brand'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'value'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['packaging'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['availability'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'avail pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['price'] = product.find('span', {'class': 'price'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
    product_details['packaging'] = product_details['packaging'][9:] # here we're cutting redundant part of string "Brand: \n\n"
    product_details['availability'] = product_details['availability'][16:] # here we're cutting redundant part of string "Availability: \n\n"
    all_product.append(product_details)

print(all_product)

with open('products.csv', 'w+') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Brand', 'Packaging', 'Availability', 'Price'])
    for product in all_product:
        writer.writerow([product['name'], product['brand'],product['packaging'], product['availability'], product['price']])
```

Here is the error code when trying two URLs:

```
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?product_list_limit=25', 'https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?p=2&product_list_limit=25']'
```

I'm always wondering if there is a way to generate, infinite pages, instead of manually placing the URLs in the urls variable. The website I am looking to scrape has thousands of products with many pages. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost finished your code, but you should follow this, if you have to access multi-url and save all data.

- save each soup
- traverse each soup and save data to a list
- write data

My full code

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ["https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?product_list_limit=25",
        "https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?p=2&product_list_limit=25"]

all_product = []

for index,url in enumerate(urls):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    products = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "product details product-item-details"})
    all_product.append(products)

resultset = []

for products in all_product:
    for product in products:
        product_details = dict()
        product_details['name'] = product.find('a').text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['brand'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'value'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['packaging'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['availability'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'avail pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['price'] = product.find('span', {'class': 'price'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['packaging'] = product_details['packaging'][9:] # here we're cutting redundant part of string "Brand: \n\n"
        product_details['availability'] = product_details['availability'][16:] # here we're cutting redundant part of string "Availability: \n\n"
        resultset.append(product_details)


with open('products.csv', 'w+',,newline='') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Brand', 'Packaging', 'Availability', 'Price'])
    for product in resultset:
        writer.writerow([product['name'], product['brand'],product['packaging'], product['availability'], product['price']])
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

you originally had

```
html = requests.get(urls).text
```

dont you want to replace the `urls` in `request.get` with `url` because as of right now your trying to request the entire array instead of each one

```
for url in urls:
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    products = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "product details product-item-details"})
    all_product = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a numeric loop and pass in the page number, as long as the URL is otherwise the same

```
for i in range(1,6):
    url = "https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?p="+str(i)+"&product_list_limit=25"
    print(url)
    #Do requests stuff here
```

produces:

```
https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?p=1&product_list_limit=25
https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?p=2&product_list_limit=25
https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?p=3&product_list_limit=25
https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?p=4&product_list_limit=25
https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?p=5&product_list_limit=25
```

Note: It may just be from pasting, but it looks like you may have indentation issues in your code that may affect what is happening in each loop