# Only last 25 objects from scraped data being transferred to CSV file

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Actual code: I am trying to scrape from several pages from a medical products website for each of their products based on different product detail features(name, brand, packaging, availability, and price). I am able to go through each of the pages and collect the data as demonstrated in the internal python output. However,  only the last 25 products are transcribed in the CSV file instead of all requested in the scraping process.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

all_product = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    url = "https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?p="+str(i)+"&product_list_limit=25"
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    products = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "product details product-item-details"})


    for product in products:
        product_details = dict()
        product_details['name'] = product.find('a').text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['brand'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'value'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['packaging'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['availability'] = product.find('div', {'class': 'avail pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['price'] = product.find('span', {'class': 'price'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ')
        product_details['packaging'] = product_details['packaging'][9:] # here we're cutting redundant part of string "Brand: \n\n"
        product_details['availability'] = product_details['availability'][16:] # here we're cutting redundant part of string "Availability: \n\n"
        all_product.append(product_details)

    print(all_product)

with open('prod.csv', 'w+') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writerow = (['Name', 'Brand', 'Packaging', 'Availability', 'Price'])
    for product in all_product:
        writer.writerow([product['name'], product['brand'],product['packaging'], product['availability'], product['price']])
```

Output provided by python:

```
[{'name': 'Kimberly Clark Blue Nitrile Exam Gloves -100/BX', 'brand': 'Kimberly Clark', 'packaging': 'Kimberly Clark', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$26.94'}, {'name': 'Pro Advantage Gloves - 200/BX', 'brand': 'Pro Advantage', 'packaging': 'Pro Advantage', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$28.94'}, {'name': 'Kimberly Clark Powder Free Exam Gloves - 500/CS', 'brand': 'Kimberly Clark', 'packaging': 'Kimberly Clark', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$136.99'}, {'name': 'Kimberly Clark Sterile Pairs Exam Gloves - 400/CS', 'brand': 'Kimberly Clark', 'packaging': 'Kimberly Clark', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$205.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Multi Care Vinyl Exam Gloves Non-Latex - 1000/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$61.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Tillotson Powder Free Plus Latex Exam Gloves - 1000/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$109.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex 6512 True Advantage High Risk Nitrile Exam Gloves, 8 mil - 500/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$105.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex 6512 True Advantage High Risk Nitrile Exam Gloves, 8 mil - 50/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$20.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Tillotson Tru Advantage PF Nitrile Exam Gloves - 1000/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$101.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Tillotson Tru Advantage PF Nitrile Exam Gloves - 100/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$18.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Tillotson Dental Care Powderless Inner Surface Latex Exam Gloves - 1000/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$110.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Tillotson Dental Care Powderless Inner Surface Latex Exam Gloves - 100/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$21.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Ultra Care Powderless Inner Surface Latex Exam Gloves - 1000/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$110.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Ultra Care Powderless Inner Surface Latex Exam Gloves - 100/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$21.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex DynaPlus Nitrile Exam Gloves - 2000/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$125.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex DynaPlus Nitrile Exam Gloves - 200/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$24.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Black Nitrile Exam Gloves (non-latex) Powder Free - 1000/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$89.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Black Nitrile Exam Gloves (non-latex) Powder Free - 100/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$17.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Sterile Latex Exam Gloves Powder Free - (Pairs) - 400 PR/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$201.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Sterile Latex Exam Gloves Powder Free - (Pairs) - 50 PR/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$41.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex High Risk Latex Exam Gloves, 15mil Blue Powder Free - 500/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$131.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex High Risk Latex Exam Gloves, 15mil Blue Powder Free - 50/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$25.00'}, {'name': 'Dynarex High Risk Latex Exam Gloves, 10mil White Powder Free - 500/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$120.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex High Risk Latex Exam Gloves, 10mil White Powder Free - 50/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$23.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Black Arrow Latex Exam Gloves - 1000/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$104.99'}]
[{'name': 'Dynarex Black Arrow Latex Exam Gloves - 100/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$19.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Safe-Touch Vinyl Exam Gloves Powder Free -1000/CS', 'brand': 'Safetouch', 'packaging': 'Safetouch', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$61.99'}, {'name': 'Halyard Health Purple Nitrile XTRA PF Extended Cuff - 50/BX', 'brand': 'Safetouch', 'packaging': 'Safetouch', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$13.95'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Safe-Touch Vinyl Exam Gloves Powder Free -100/BX', 'brand': 'Safetouch', 'packaging': 'Safetouch', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$13.99'}, {'name': 'Pro Advantage Vinyl Exam Glove, Powder Free - 100/BX', 'brand': 'Pro Advantage', 'packaging': 'Pro Advantage', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$14.94'}, {'name': 'BSN Medical Therall Arthritis Gloves SM -1/PR', 'brand': 'BSN Medical', 'packaging': 'BSN Medical', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$37.94'}, {'name': 'Kimberly Clark Exam Glove, PF Nitrile - 200 PR/CS', 'brand': 'Kimberly Clark', 'packaging': 'Kimberly Clark', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$181.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Safe-Touch Latex Exam Gloves Powder Free -1000/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$89.99'}, {'name': 'Dynarex Safe-Touch Powder Free Latex Exam Gloves - 100/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$17.99'}, {'name': 'Molnlycke Health Care Biogel Surgeons Glove ST Latex P/F - 50/BX', 'brand': 'Biogel', 'packaging': 'Biogel', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$119.95'}, {'name': 'Spectra 360 Electrode Gel - 60 Gram Tube', 'brand': 'Biogel', 'packaging': 'Biogel', 'availability': '199 in stock', 'price': '$1.99'}, {'name': 'Latex Surgeons Gloves Powder Free – Sterile Pairs - 200/CS', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$131.99'}, {'name': 'Latex Surgeons Gloves Powder Free – Sterile Pairs - 50/BX', 'brand': 'Dynarex', 'packaging': 'Dynarex', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$47.99'}, {'name': 'Welch Allyn 97250 3.5 V Diagnostic Set with Coaxial Opthalmoscope / Diagnostic Otoscope Handle and Hard Case', 'brand': 'Welch Allyn', 'packaging': ' Welch Allyn', 'availability': '831 in stock', 'price': '$399.00'}, {'name': 'Chattanooga 4004 Stainless Steel Mobile Cart - 3 Shelves - 1/EA', 'brand': 'Chattanooga', 'packaging': 'Chattanooga', 'availability': '1 in stock', 'price': '$288.92'}, {'name': 'Chattanooga 4018 Stainless Steel Mobile Cart - 2 Shelves with Drawer - 1/EA', 'brand': 'Chattanooga', 'packaging': 'Chattanooga', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$474.95'}, {'name': 'Chattanooga 630309-001 Saunders Education Manuals- Managing Back Pain -1/EA', 'brand': 'Saunders', 'packaging': 'Saunders', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$5.95'}, {'name': 'Chattanooga Pnematic Stool with Back - 1/EA', 'brand': 'Chattanooga', 'packaging': 'Chattanooga', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$149.95'}, {'name': 'Chattanooga 77062 Pnematic Stool without Back - Dove Gray - 1/EA', 'brand': 'Chattanooga', 'packaging': 'Chattanooga', 'availability': '4 in stock', 'price': '$129.95'}, {'name': 'Chattanooga 7706 Pnematic Stool without Back - Burgundy - 1/EA', 'brand': 'Chattanooga', 'packaging': 'Chattanooga', 'availability': '78 in stock', 'price': '$129.00'}, {'name': 'Welch Allyn 08800-U 4.6 V Halogen Lamp for KleenSpec Vaginal Specula Illumination Systems (#78812, #78814, #78816)', 'brand': 'Welch Allyn', 'packaging': 'Welch Allyn', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$28.00'}, {'name': 'Halyard Health Fluidshield Fog Free Procedure Mask - Orange - Box of 40', 'brand': 'Welch Allyn', 'packaging': 'Welch Allyn', 'availability': '66 in stock', 'price': '$15.99'}, {'name': 'Welch Allyn 45008-0000 Welch Allyn Silver/Silver Chloride Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 1000/BX', 'brand': 'Welch Allyn', 'packaging': 'Welch Allyn', 'availability': '14 in stock', 'price': '$119.95'}, {'name': 'Welch Allyn 45008-0000 Welch Allyn Silver/Silver Chloride Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK', 'brand': 'Welch Allyn', 'packaging': 'Welch Allyn', 'availability': '141 in stock', 'price': '$13.95'}, {'name': 'Vermed A10009-100F Silverest Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK', 'brand': 'Welch Allyn', 'packaging': 'Welch Allyn', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$21.95'}]





[{'name': 'Nikomed 0815 Nikotab Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode Pediatric - 5000/CS', 'brand': '5000/CS', 'packaging': ': \n5000/CS', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$189.95'}, {'name': 'Nikomed 0815 Nikotab Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode Pediatric - 500/BX', 'brand': '500/BX', 'packaging': ': \n500/BX', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$24.95'}, {'name': 'Nikomed 0515 Nikotab Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 500/BX', 'brand': '500/BX', 'packaging': ': \n500/BX', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$29.95'}, {'name': 'Nikomed 0515 Nikotab Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK', 'brand': '100/PK', 'packaging': ': \n100/PK', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$11.95'}, {'name': 'Nikomed 0315 Nikotab Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 5000/CS', 'brand': '5000/CS', 'packaging': ': \n5000/CS', 'availability': '37 in stock', 'price': '$199.95'}, {'name': 'Nikomed 0315 Nikotab Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 500/BX', 'brand': '500/BX', 'packaging': ': \n500/BX', 'availability': '379 in stock', 'price': '$22.95'}, {'name': 'Nikomed 0315 Nikotab Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK', 'brand': '100/PK', 'packaging': ': \n100/PK', 'availability': '37 in stock', 'price': '$9.95'}, {'name': 'Nikomed 5533-5 Trace 1 Foam Monitoring ECG Electrode - 300/BX', 'brand': '300/BX', 'packaging': ': \n300/BX', 'availability': '2 in stock', 'price': '$62.95'}, {'name': 'Medline MDS616101A Medline Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 5000/CS', 'brand': 'Medline', 'packaging': 'Medline', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$199.95'}, {'name': 'Medline MDS616101AZ Medline Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 500/BX', 'brand': 'Medline', 'packaging': 'Medline', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$22.95'}, {'name': 'Covidien ES40281 Soft-E Cloth Monitoring ECG Electrode Pediatric - 450/CS', 'brand': 'Covidien, Soft-E', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Soft-E', 'availability': '1 in stock', 'price': '$154.95'}, {'name': 'Covidien ES40281 Soft-E Cloth Monitoring ECG Electrode Pediatric - 30/PK', 'brand': 'Covidien, Soft-E', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Soft-E', 'availability': '15 in stock', 'price': '$16.95'}, {'name': 'Covidien 22450 Medi-Trace 450 Series Foam Monitoring Electrodes - 50/PK', 'brand': 'Covidien, Kendall, Medi-Trace', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Kendall, Medi-Trace', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$11.95'}, {'name': 'Covidien 30807732 Q-Trace Resting Tab ECG Electrode with Aggressive Adhesive - 2000/CS', 'brand': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$90.00'}, {'name': 'Covidien 30807732 Q-Trace Resting Tab ECG Electrode with Aggressive Adhesive - 100/PK', 'brand': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$6.50'}, {'name': 'Covidien 31447793 Kendall Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 4000/CS', 'brand': 'Covidien, Kendall', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Kendall', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$249.95'}, {'name': 'Covidien 31447793 Kendall Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK 10PK/BX', 'brand': 'Covidien, Kendall', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Kendall', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$64.95'}, {'name': 'Covidien 31447793 Kendall Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK', 'brand': 'Covidien, Kendall', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Kendall', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$7.95'}, {'name': 'Covidien Ef00149 Kendall Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 4000/CS', 'brand': 'Cleartrace 2, Conmed', 'packaging': 'Cleartrace 2, Conmed', 'availability': '5 in stock', 'price': '$169.95'}, {'name': 'Conmed 1700-005 Cleartrace Tape Monitoring ECG Electrode 5" x 10" - 600/CS', 'brand': 'Cleartrace, Conmed', 'packaging': 'Cleartrace, Conmed', 'availability': '1 in stock', 'price': '$149.95'}, {'name': 'Conmed 1700-005 Cleartrace Tape Monitoring ECG Electrode 5" x 10" - 50/BX', 'brand': 'Cleartrace, Conmed', 'packaging': 'Cleartrace, Conmed', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$12.95'}, {'name': 'Conmed 1700-003 Cleartrace Tape Monitoring ECG Electrode 3" x 10" - 600/CS', 'brand': 'Cleartrace, Conmed', 'packaging': 'Cleartrace, Conmed', 'availability': '3-5 Days', 'price': '$159.95'}, {'name': 'Conmed 1700-003 Cleartrace Tape Monitoring ECG Electrode 3" x 10" - 30/BX', 'brand': 'Cleartrace, Conmed', 'packaging': 'Cleartrace, Conmed', 'availability': '3-5 Days', 'price': '$10.50'}, {'name': 'Burdick 015-0630-00 Blue Max Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK', 'brand': 'Blue Max, Burdick', 'packaging': 'Blue Max, Burdick', 'availability': '3-5 Days', 'price': '$17.50'}, {'name': 'Burdick 047029 CardioSens Ultra II Silver/Silver Chloride Resting Tab ECG Electrode with Aggressive Adhesive - 5000/CS', 'brand': 'Burdick, CardioSens', 'packaging': 'Burdick, CardioSens', 'availability': '1 in stock', 'price': '$479.95'}]
[{'name': 'Burdick 047029 CardioSens Ultra II Silver/Silver Chloride Resting Tab ECG Electrode with Aggressive Adhesive - 500/BX', 'brand': 'Burdick, CardioSens', 'packaging': 'Burdick, CardioSens', 'availability': '16 in stock', 'price': '$49.95'}, {'name': 'Bio-Protech T716 Telectrode Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 4000/CS', 'brand': 'Bio-Protech', 'packaging': 'Bio-Protech', 'availability': '12 in stock', 'price': '$390.00'}, {'name': 'Bio-Protech T716 Telectrode Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 1000/BX', 'brand': 'Bio-Protech', 'packaging': ' Bio-Protech', 'availability': '48 in stock', 'price': '$110.00'}, {'name': 'Bio-Protech Pt2334 PRO-TAB Tape Resting ECG Electrodes - 5000/CS', 'brand': 'Bio-Protech', 'packaging': 'Bio-Protech', 'availability': '33 in stock', 'price': '$189.95'}, {'name': '3M 2570-3 Red Dot Foam Monitoring ECG Electrode with Abrader- Pack of 3', 'brand': '3M, Red Dot', 'packaging': '3M, Red Dot', 'availability': '400 in stock', 'price': '$2.99'}, {'name': 'Clarity CT-DTG-PLUS2 HCG Pregnancy Test - 25 Tests - Urine Cassette', 'brand': '3M, Red Dot', 'packaging': '3M, Red Dot', 'availability': '33 in stock', 'price': '$24.99'}, {'name': 'BSN Medical Jobst Medicalwear Glove With Velcro - 1/EA', 'brand': '3M, Red Dot', 'packaging': '3M, Red Dot', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$41.60'}, {'name': 'Welch Allyn ProBP 2400 Digital Blood Pressure Device', 'brand': '3M, Red Dot', 'packaging': '3M, Red Dot', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$430.00'}, {'name': 'Covidien 31433538 5400 Diagnostic Tab ECG Electrodes- Case of 4000', 'brand': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$160.00'}, {'name': 'Covidien 31433538 Q-Trace Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK', 'brand': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$48.00'}, {'name': 'Covidien 31433538 Q-Trace Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK', 'brand': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$4.99'}, {'name': 'Unistik 3 Normal Safety Lancets 23G X 1.88mm Yellow - Box of 50', 'brand': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'availability': '73 in stock', 'price': '$9.99'}, {'name': 'SEK-141 Osom Dipstick Strep A Test Kit, 50/BX', 'brand': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$89.99'}, {'name': '3M-5639 Littmann Classic III Stethoscope, SS Finish Chestpiece, Pink Tube, 27" ,1/EA', 'brand': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'packaging': 'Covidien, Q-Trace', 'availability': '1-3 Days', 'price': '$79.00'}, {'name': '3M-5621 Littmann Classic III Stethoscope, SS Finish Chestpiece, Gray Tube, 27" ,1/EA', 'brand': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III', 'packaging': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III', 'availability': '5-10 Days', 'price': '$79.00'}, {'name': 'Welch Allyn 97150-M 3.5v Diagnostic Set Opthalmoscope / Otoscope with Rechargeable Handle and Hard Case', 'brand': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III', 'packaging': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III', 'availability': '2 in stock', 'price': '$515.00'}, {'name': '3M 5627 Stethoscope, Standard-Finish Chestpiece, Burgundy Tube, 27', 'brand': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III', 'packaging': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III', 'availability': '1 in stock', 'price': '$79.00'}, {'name': 'Welch Allyn 23810-SET 3.5v Macroview Otoscope with Handle and Hard Case', 'brand': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III', 'packaging': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III', 'availability': '6 in stock', 'price': '$265.00'}, {'name': 'Omron 7321-E M6 Comfort Digital Blood Pressure Monitor', 'brand': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III', 'packaging': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III', 'availability': '10 in stock', 'price': '$120.00'}, {'name': 'Welch Allyn 06000-200N Braun Thermoscan Pro 6000 Ear Thermometer with Large Cradle', 'brand': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III', 'packaging': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III', 'availability': '3 in stock', 'price': '$199.00'}, {'name': 'Covidien Ef00149 Kendall Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 1000/BX', 'brand': 'Cleartrace 2, Conmed', 'packaging': 'Cleartrace 2, Conmed', 'availability': '20 in stock', 'price': '$55.00'}, {'name': 'Covidien Ef00149 Kendall Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK', 'brand': 'Cleartrace 2, Conmed', 'packaging': 'Cleartrace 2, Conmed', 'availability': '208 in stock', 'price': '$7.50'}, {'name': '3M 6158 Littmann Cardiology IV Stethoscope, 27" Raspberry Tubing, 1/EA', 'brand': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Cardiology IV', 'packaging': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Cardiology IV', 'availability': '21 in stock', 'price': '$168.00'}, {'name': '3M 6157 Littmann Cardiology IV Stethoscope, 27" Caribbean Blue Tubing, 1/EA', 'brand': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Cardiology IV', 'packaging': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Cardiology IV', 'availability': '9 in stock', 'price': '$168.00'}, {'name': '3M 6156 Littmann Cardiology IV Stethoscope, 27" Plum Tubing, 1/EA', 'brand': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Cardiology IV', 'packaging': '3M, Littmann, Littmann Cardiology IV', 'availability': '103 in stock', 'price': '$168.00'}]
```

Output in CSV File:

```
Burdick 047029 CardioSens Ultra II Silver/Silver Chloride Resting Tab ECG Electrode with Aggressive Adhesive - 500/BX,"Burdick, CardioSens","Burdick, CardioSens",16 in stock,$49.95

Bio-Protech T716 Telectrode Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 4000/CS,Bio-Protech,Bio-Protech,12 in stock,$390.00

Bio-Protech T716 Telectrode Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 1000/BX,Bio-Protech, Bio-Protech,48 in stock,$110.00

Bio-Protech Pt2334 PRO-TAB Tape Resting ECG Electrodes - 5000/CS,Bio-Protech,Bio-Protech,33 in stock,$189.95

3M 2570-3 Red Dot Foam Monitoring ECG Electrode with Abrader- Pack of 3,"3M, Red Dot","3M, Red Dot",400 in stock,$2.99

Clarity CT-DTG-PLUS2 HCG Pregnancy Test - 25 Tests - Urine Cassette,"3M, Red Dot","3M, Red Dot",33 in stock,$24.99

BSN Medical Jobst Medicalwear Glove With Velcro - 1/EA,"3M, Red Dot","3M, Red Dot",5-10 Days,$41.60

Welch Allyn ProBP 2400 Digital Blood Pressure Device,"3M, Red Dot","3M, Red Dot",5-10 Days,$430.00

Covidien 31433538 5400 Diagnostic Tab ECG Electrodes- Case of 4000,"Covidien, Q-Trace","Covidien, Q-Trace",5-10 Days,$160.00

Covidien 31433538 Q-Trace Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK,"Covidien, Q-Trace","Covidien, Q-Trace",5-10 Days,$48.00

Covidien 31433538 Q-Trace Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK,"Covidien, Q-Trace","Covidien, Q-Trace",5-10 Days,$4.99

Unistik 3 Normal Safety Lancets 23G X 1.88mm Yellow - Box of 50,"Covidien, Q-Trace","Covidien, Q-Trace",73 in stock,$9.99

"SEK-141 Osom Dipstick Strep A Test Kit, 50/BX","Covidien, Q-Trace","Covidien, Q-Trace",5-10 Days,$89.99

"3M-5639 Littmann Classic III Stethoscope, SS Finish Chestpiece, Pink Tube, 27"" ,1/EA","Covidien, Q-Trace","Covidien, Q-Trace",1-3 Days,$79.00

"3M-5621 Littmann Classic III Stethoscope, SS Finish Chestpiece, Gray Tube, 27"" ,1/EA","3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III","3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III",5-10 Days,$79.00

Welch Allyn 97150-M 3.5v Diagnostic Set Opthalmoscope / Otoscope with Rechargeable Handle and Hard Case,"3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III","3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III",2 in stock,$515.00

"3M 5627 Stethoscope, Standard-Finish Chestpiece, Burgundy Tube, 27","3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III","3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III",1 in stock,$79.00

Welch Allyn 23810-SET 3.5v Macroview Otoscope with Handle and Hard Case,"3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III","3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III",6 in stock,$265.00

Omron 7321-E M6 Comfort Digital Blood Pressure Monitor,"3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III","3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III",10 in stock,$120.00

Welch Allyn 06000-200N Braun Thermoscan Pro 6000 Ear Thermometer with Large Cradle,"3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III","3M, Littmann, Littmann Classic III",3 in stock,$199.00

Covidien Ef00149 Kendall Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 1000/BX,"Cleartrace 2, Conmed","Cleartrace 2, Conmed",20 in stock,$55.00

Covidien Ef00149 Kendall Foam Resting Tab ECG Electrode - 100/PK,"Cleartrace 2, Conmed","Cleartrace 2, Conmed",208 in stock,$7.50

"3M 6158 Littmann Cardiology IV Stethoscope, 27"" Raspberry Tubing, 1/EA","3M, Littmann, Littmann Cardiology IV","3M, Littmann, Littmann Cardiology IV",21 in stock,$168.00

"3M 6157 Littmann Cardiology IV Stethoscope, 27"" Caribbean Blue Tubing, 1/EA","3M, Littmann, Littmann Cardiology IV","3M, Littmann, Littmann Cardiology IV",9 in stock,$168.00

"3M 6156 Littmann Cardiology IV Stethoscope, 27"" Plum Tubing, 1/EA","3M, Littmann, Littmann Cardiology IV","3M, Littmann, Littmann Cardiology IV",103 in stock,$168.00
```

So, as you can see, there were only 25 of the remainder of the 125 product list written onto the CSV. Is there any way to include all of the data scraped that was output by Python?

Comment: I couldn't replicate it, I get a csv file with 207 lines, so about 103 outputs

Comment: Huh? that's odd. Maybe it's something with the method I use to make a file.. BTW it could be 103 products, my 125 was an estimate.

Comment: How certain are you that your file is only 25 outputs long, is it possible to scroll?

Comment: 100% certain, just count the lines in the CSV output i have on the 3rd code output section. Each line is 1 product.

Comment: I suggest you add a print statement `print(len(all_product))`, as well as add a counter which you print with each iteration. Just to check if your input is correct, if it is, something is wrong in your writing statement, if it is not something is wrong in your way of collecting it. But again: I have no trouble running it.

Comment: I'm an idiot, i had several different files that were named 'prod', and I was checking the wrong one every time. The right one was in a different location. Thanks for testing out my code, much appreciated. The only issue, now is, i still not have the headers of the categories!

Comment: Glad you found the problem. I'm not quite sure you mean with headers for the categories though

Comment: Near the bottom of the code 'writerow = (['Name', 'Brand', 'Packaging', 'Availability', 'Price'])', this should implement the top row to say 'Name, 'Brand', 'Packaging', 'Availability', and 'Price'. Instead the first row is the first product. I might be nit-picking but, it is stated in the code.

Comment: can you not simply add the line: `writer.writerow(['Name', 'Brand', 'Packaging', 'Availability', 'Price'])` before you initiate the loop?

Comment: you are asking a same question, i have already answered one. You only change a few that you can get what you excepted. [Your question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176773/trying-to-scrape-multiple-urls-can-only-scrape-1-any-way-to-generate-multiple/53184642#53184642). If my answer solved you problem, close this one now  and accept the answer which solved your question.

Comment: Why are you putting the scraped data in a dict? Why not just assign them in a list of a list? I get the whole dict thing but I think it is useless at this point, right? I never assign any scraped data that way, I just assign each value a variable name, then append the list at the end `all_product.append([name, brand, etc, etc, etc]). Then when you loop through it usually doesn't have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets me 125 products. Also, you weren't writing the header data on the first row. I changed that and it all seems to be good. Try increasing your range from a `5` to a `6` to get 25 more responses.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

all_product = []

for i in range(1, 6):
    url = "https://www.medplusmedicalsupply.com/exam-and-diagnostic?p="+str(i)+"&product_list_limit=25"
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    products = soup.findAll('div', class_="product details product-item-details")

    for product in products:
        name = product.find('a').text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip(
            '\n\r\t": ').strip()
        brand = product.find('div', {'class': 'value'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip(
            '\n\r\t": ').strip()
        packaging = product.find('div', {'class': 'pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip(
            '\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip()
        availability = product.find('div', {'class': 'avail pack'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip(
            '\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip()
        price = product.find('span', {'class': 'price'}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ').strip(
            '\n\r\t": ').strip('\n\r\t": ').strip()
        packaging = packaging[9:].replace(':', '')  # here were cutting redundant part of string "Brand: \n\n"
        availability = availability[16:]  # here we're cutting redundant part of string "Availability: \n\n"
        all_product.append([name, brand, packaging, availability, price])

print(len(all_product))
with open('prod.csv', 'w+') as csvFile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    csv_writer.writerow(["Name", "Brand", "Packaging", "Availability", "Price"])
    for product in all_product:
        csv_writer.writerow(product)
```